# Calculating totals in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Model called JobReport which looks like this (simplified)

```
public class JobReport
{
    public JobReport()   
    {
        WorkOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
    }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public decimal WorkOrderTotal {get; set; }
    public List<WorkOrder> WorkOrders{ get; set; }
}

public class WorkOrder
{
    public WorkOrder()   
    {
        Total = 0;
    }
    public string Trade { get; set; }
    public int WorkOrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Total { get; set; }
}
```

I now have a Linq query which gets me all the Jobs that have WorkOrders that have a trade which is in a passed array thanks to [Linq Query where related entity contains value from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234490/linq-query-where-related-entity-contains-value-from-array):

```
jobs = jobs
.Where(x => x.WorkOrders.Any(y => trades.Contains(y.Trade)));
```

How do I now get the WorkOrderTotal, which is the sum of the Total in the workorders that meet the predicate of the above query?  I can't see how to add .Sum() anywhere?

EDIT

Just to confirm, each job needs the sum of it's workorders that are in the given trades.

Comment: I'm not sure what to try, Intellisense isn't giving me any options to add a Sum() anywhere in the predicate

Comment: d\do you need the total of workorders for each job or the total of all workorders in all the jobs ?

Comment: It looks like you want to assign a property of an existing object... in a LINQ query. Not really what LINQ queries are for.

Comment: Aren't I just trying to Sum a value within the model?  Ie,"Give me the value of the workorders for each job where where the workorders are for a particular trade"

Comment: @RobbieMills it was relay hard to understand what you were going for.. 
people took the time to help you out. and conducted a conversation and gave partial answer that helped some one eventually give a full answer. 
So it's good that you accepted the full answer. but that is still one way you can mark these answers as helpful and show your appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly easier solution to those already posted would be to add a property to your JobReport called WorkOrderValue:

```
public decimal? WorkOrdersValue { get; set; }
```

Now you can query on the jobs that meet your criteria:

```
jobs = jobs
    .Where(x => x.WorkOrders
        .Any(y => trades.Contains(y.Trade.ToLower())))
        .ToList();
```

And separately calculate the total for each job:

```
foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    job.WorkOrdersValue = job.WorkOrders.Where
        (y => trades.Contains(y.Trade.ToLower())).Sum(wo => wo.Total);
}
```

Comment: This is the one I ended up going with, was easiest to implement and get working

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    IEnumerable<decimal> workOrderTotals = jobs
        .Where(x => x.WorkOrders.Any(y => trades.Contains(y.Trade)))
        .Select( j => j.WorkOrders.Sum(wo => wo.Total ?? 0));
```

And here's a test case :

```
  var jobs = new List<JobReport>();
        jobs.Add(new JobReport{ WorkOrders = new List<WorkOrder>{ new WorkOrder{ Total = 10} }});
        jobs.Add(new JobReport { WorkOrders = new List<WorkOrder> { new WorkOrder { Total = 10 }, new WorkOrder { Total = 10 } } });
```

The result is an enumerable containing 2 values   10 , 20

Comment: This gives the total of all the jobs, not the total for each job?

Comment: i added a test case. with 2 jobs you get the total of all the workorders for each job

Comment: I see, that helps a lot, however if I have 3 jobs and only job 1 and 3 meets the query parameters, how can I align the enumerable to the correct job?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this as the test data

```
        JobReport job1 = new JobReport();
        job1.JobID = 1;
        job1.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 2, Trade = "trade1", Total = 10});
        job1.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 3, Trade = "trade2", Total = 20 });
        job1.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 4, Trade = "trade1", Total = 25 });

        JobReport job2 = new JobReport();
        job2.JobID = 2;
        job2.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 1, Trade = "trade1", Total = 10 });
        job2.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 5, Trade = "trade2", Total = 20 });
        job2.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 6, Trade = "trade2", Total = 30 });
        job2.WorkOrders.Add(new WorkOrder() { WorkOrderID = 7, Trade = "trade3", Total = 10 });

        List<JobReport> jobs = new List<JobReport>();
        jobs.Add(job1);
        jobs.Add(job2);
```

You could do something like this.

```
var groupedJobs = jobs.GroupBy(a => a.JobID)
            .Select(b => new { JobId = b.Key, WorkOrdersByTrade = b.Select(c => c.WorkOrders.GroupBy(d => d.Trade)
            .Select(g => new { Trade = g.Key, tradeSum = g.Sum(s => s.Total) })) });
```

Further by defining the following classes

```
    public class TradeTotal
    {
        public string Trade { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }
    }

    public class JobTrade
    {
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public List<TradeTotal> TradeTotals { get; set; }
    }
```

You can get the results in the format that you wanted

```
var JobTradeList = groupedJobs.Select(x => new JobTrade() { JobId = x.JobId, TradeTotals = x.WorkOrdersByTrade.SelectMany(s => s.Select(v => new TradeTotal() { Total = v.tradeSum, Trade = v.Trade })).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Code may be not 100% clean; but I think this is what you are after.

[image]